# Unexpected token < when using json

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am having the following error when performing xmlxttp request :
Unexpected token < 
my js code :

```
 function getInfo(){
        var xhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for modern browsers
    var std = document.getElementById("std").value;
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        var stdInfo = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        document.getElementById("id").value=stdInfo[0].id;
        document.getElementById("name").value=stdInfo[0].name;
        document.getElementById("address").value=stdInfo[0].address;
        document.getElementById("descripton").value=stdInfo[0].description;
    }
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "update.php?std="+std, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

and the php code is :

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8");
   $name = $_GET['std'];
   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","School3");

    mysqli_query($con, 'SET NAMES "utf8" COLLATE "utf8_general_ci"' );
     if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

     }

     $result=mysqli_query($con,'select * from student where name=\''.$name.'\'');
     $student="[";
     while ($raw=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
         $student.= '{"id":"'  . $raw["id"] . '",';
    $student .= '"name":"'   . $raw["name"]        . '",';
    $student .= '"address":"'. $raw["address"]     . '"}'; 
     }
     $student="]";

     echo($student);
     ?>
```

I have tried the following two solution but nothing works :
first I replaced :

```
header("Conhtent-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8");
```

with this :

```
header("Conhtent-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

and I have tried echo($student) insted of echo (json_encode($student)),,

what is the problem ?

Comment: Make sure you are getting valid `json` string in response. It seems you are getting `html` or `xml`

Comment: There's a typo in your `Content-Type`-header ;)

Comment: Go to the Network tab of Developer Tools/Firebug, and look at the AJAX response. You'll probably see what you're doing wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
$student="[";
while ($raw=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $student.= '{"id":"'  . $result["id"] . '",';
    $student .= '"name":"'   . $rs["name"]        . '",';
    $student .= '"address":"'. $rs["address"]     . '"}'; 
}
$student="]";
```

is already creating a json-like string, if it wasn't buggy on the last line, where you overwrite the contents of `$student` variable. So you can not use `json_encode` function. And just `echo ($student);`

But I strongly recommend to use this function, as it will do all bad job for you - like escaping characters, and adding commas after each object, which your script **definitely not do**. And rewrite your code like this:

```
$student = array();
while ($raw=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $student[] = array(
        "id" => $result["id"],  // maybe $raw['id']
        "name" => $rs["name"],  // maybe $raw['name']
        "address" => $rs["address"],    // maybe $raw['address']
    );
}
echo(json_encode($student));
```

Comment: I have mentioned that I have tried echo($student) without echo(json_encode($student))

Comment: Your last line `$student="]";` overwrites everything. All you get on client is a `']'`. Do you think it is a JSON?

Comment: I have tried the solution , still getting the same error

Comment: the seconde one in ur answer

Comment: There are two of them. I advise you to follow the second one. And open your developers console and check what your script returns via `console.log()`

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the response you get in the browser (by using the internal inspector for example). Chances are, you're getting a error from PHP, which will produce HTML code in your response. (The unexpected `<`.)

Second, you don't have to `json_encode`, because you're already trying to produce a string with JSON code. Instead try to make the `$student` a object or array, fill it with the rows and then `echo` the `json_encode`d `$student`.

Third, the `$result["id"]` and `$rs[..]`'s should be `$raw`, since that is the name of the variable you're fetching the MySQL rows into.

Fourth, don't use `ob_clean();`. It has no purpose. If there's an error thrown by PHP, you need to address/fix that. (not try to remove the error message ;) )

Last, but not least, you are doing `$student="]";`, which makes everything before void and setting ']' as the value of `$student`.

Ps: Don't forget to include a `description` in the `$student` variable, since your JavaScript is expecting it

Comment: I have tried echo($student) without json_encoder also I have tried to change the strcture of the result to an array and then use json encode but still not working

Comment: What is the contents of the response?

Comment: @ahmedmostafa The reason for the error has nothing to do with how you're encoding the JSON (although that has problems). The problem is that you're sending HTML **in addition to** the JSON.

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: @ahmedmostafa your server is responding with html, for some reason or another not explainable by the code in your question.